# How to ignore single quotes in regex using preg_replace function in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, symfony, twig

I am basically trying to transform any hash-tagged word in a string into a link:

Here is what my code looks like:

```
public function linkify($text)
{
    // ... generating $url
    $text = preg_replace("/\B#(\w+)/", "<a href=" . $url . "/$1>#$1</a>", $text);

    return $text;
}
```

It works pretty good excepting the case when that $text contains a single quote. Here are

Example1:

> "What is your #name ?"
>
> Result: "What is your [#name](http://google.com)?"  Works fine.

Example2:

> "What's your #name ?"
>
> Result: "What&[#039](http://google.com);s your [#name](http://google.com)?"  Does not work, I want
>   this result: "What's your [#name](http://google.com)?"

Any idea about how I can get rid of that single quote problem using PHP ?

EDIT1:
Just for info, before or after html_entity_decode($text) I got
"What&[#039](http://google.com);s your [#name](http://google.com)?"

Comment: Try escaping with \ (using \' instead)

Comment: Assuming the content comes from the user.... this is a bad idea. Turning user supplied text into uninterpolated HTML will result in vulnerability to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
$string = "' \'' '"; 
$string = preg_replace("#[\\\\']#", "\'", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is protecting your html entities. This can save your life if the string is coming from a get/post request - but iI it's from a trusted source just use html_entity_decode to convert it back.  This 39-thing is a way to express the single quote as you might have realized.

Comment: It must. Please output your string to a text file to see what's ACTUALLY in there.

Comment: Before and after $text_decode = html_entity_decode($text); I have "What&#039;s your #name?"

Answer (score 1):

if the problem is html_entities, then maybe you only need to html_entity_decode your $text

```
$text = preg_replace("/\B#(\w+)/", "<a href=" . $url . "/html_entity_decode($1)>#$1</a>", $text);
```

Comment: try to html_entity_decode before return the url.
result html_entity_decode($text);

Comment: Finally done with this : html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES); @harry S

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions, I've finally sorted this out with this :

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```